# Python and Scipy programming

Tags: python, scipy

I'm getting this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/test", line 14, in <module>
    tck = interpolate.bisplrep(X,Y,Z)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\interpolate\fitpack.py", line 850, in bisplrep
    raise TypeError('m >= (kx+1)(ky+1) must hold')
TypeError: m >= (kx+1)(ky+1) must hold
```

The error says that `len(X) = m is <=(kx+1)(ky+1)`. How can I solve this? Here's my program:

```
import scipy
import math
import numpy
from scipy import interpolate


x= [1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000]
y= [1000]

Y = numpy.array([[i]*len(x) for i in y])
X = numpy.array([x for i in y])
Z = numpy.array([[21284473.74,2574509.71,453334.97,95761.64,30580.45,25580.60]]) 

tck = interpolate.bisplrep(x,y,Z)
print interpolate.bisplev(3500,1000,tck)
```

Comment: Um, are you using `interpolate.bisplrep(X,Y,Z)` (as your traceback says) or `interpolate.bisplrep(x,y,Z)` (as your code sample says)?

Answer (score 5):

Have you read the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.bisplrep.html)?

If you don't specify `kx` and `ky`, default values will be `3`:

```
scipy.interpolate.bisplrep(x, y, z, w=None, xb=None, xe=None, yb=None, ye=None, 
                           kx=3, ky=3, task=0, s=None, eps=1e-16, tx=None, ty=None,
                           full_output=0, nxest=None, nyest=None, quiet=1)
```

And of course, `len(X) = 6 < 16 = (3+1)(3+1)`.

Even if you give `kx=1` and `ky=1` explicitly while calling, you have another problem. Your `(x,y)` values form a line, and you can not define a surface from a line. Therefore it  gives you `ValueError: Invalid inputs.`. First, you should fix your data. If this is your data, as you have no variation in `Y`, skip it and do a spline in 2D with `X` and `Z`.